# How to loop over Map<String, Array<Any>> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

In my android app with Kotlin, I have a variable "data" type of  Map>,Which Product is a kotlin data class.

```
var data: Map<String, Array<Product>>
```

Product data class contains var availableQuantities.
I want to loop the Map> and conserve only the product with availableQuantities != 0, and update the data variable.How can I do this?
Here's my code

```
   try {
        val filteredMap: HashMap<String, Array<Product>> = HashMap()
        data.forEach { (key, value) ->
            val filtered = value.filter { prod -> prod.availableQuantities != 0 }
            if (filtered.isNotEmpty()) {
                filteredMap[key] = filtered.toTypedArray()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.message
    }
```

But, after running the code an exception appear as the following image :

The following image is the description of data :

[image]

How can I correct my code to make it functionnal?

Comment: Do you need result as Map or a just List of Products ?

Comment: I Need a result as Map, I want to update "data"

Comment: When you say your "app is blocked" in various comments below, do you mean that it crashes or that it hangs?

Comment: I add try catch to my code and I get the following exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.models.Product[]

Answer (score 1):

I think it could use `.values.flatten()` to make a flat list.

```
  val tempProd = data.values.flatten().filter {
            it.availableQuantities != 0
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
val tempProd = StreamSupport.stream(data.values.toMutableList())
            .map{t -> t.filter{
                it.availableQuantities!= 0
            } }
```

You might get empty arrays though, since it's an array of arrays. If you only want a single array, you'd need to reduce the two-dimensional array

Comment: No, didn't work
I want to loop the data, and update it with only th Product with quantity not zero 
Did you get me ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Stream`, you could simply benefit on kotlin extension functions and get rid of empty arrays aswell using `flatMap {}` in order to merge all arrays of `Product` to single list.

So Your scenario would look like:

```kotlin
val temp = data.values.flatMap { products ->
    products.filter { product ->
        product.quantity != 0
    }
}
```

Comment: When, I use your answer, the app is blocked

Comment: what is the message ?

Comment: There's no message, only is blocked even if I debug

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.mapValues { (_, array) ->
    array.filter { it.availableQuantities != 0 }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Comment: I like ur answer, but the app is blocked I don't know why

Comment: It's a dynamic map, it's not statique

Comment: @Lina at the time when you use this code and the app is blocked. Anyway use it in different thread then

Comment: Yes, When I debug the app, only the message "the application is running" is appear

Comment: I add try catch to my code and I get the following exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.models.Product[]

Comment: Are you using `as Array<Product>` instead of `toTypedArray()`?

Comment: @IR42: Your answer is code-wise okay, but I suggest that you improve it by explaining why this structure is good and how it works.

Comment: @Tenfour04 : yes, I try it 
but always the exception

Comment: That's the problem. You are trying to cast a List to an Array, which is impossible. Use `toTypedArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases i can think of .If you do not want to keep empty product list against a Key.

```
val filteredMap: HashMap<String, Array<Product>> = HashMap()
data.forEach { (key, value) ->
    val filtered=value.filter {prod-> prod.availableQuantities!=0 }
    if(filtered.isNotEmpty()){
        filteredMap[key]=filtered.toTypedArray()
    }
 }
```

Or if you want to keep empty list against a Key then you can try something like :-

```
val filteredMap= data.mapValues { (_, value) ->
    value.filter { it.availableQuantities != 0 }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, thank you
But, I don't know why it not work

Comment: the app is  blocked even if I debug, I don't know

Comment: I add try catch to my code and I get the following exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.models.Product[]

Comment: Edit your question with updated code .. i have tested this code it should work efficiently .. If you use `Map<String, ArrayList<Product>>` instead of `Map<String, Array<Product>>` things will be a bit easy ..

Comment: We couldn't write a code as the following ?  "  val tempVariant = StreamSupport.stream(data.toList())
                    .filter { o1 -> o1.second {it  -> }
                    .collect(Collectors.toList<>())"

Comment: how can I change data: Map<String, Array<ProductData>>, to Map<String, ArrayList<Product>>

Comment: The Exception you have posted is not related the code you have in question.. You should debug your code .. This exception probably  coming from the code which you call filtering after . you are passing `ArrayList` instead of `ProductData` Array.. Can't help without seeing any code